# What do you call a society after it collapses to a certain degree?

Tags: society, post-apocalypse, natural-disasters

I've been thinking about phrases like "a post-apocalyptic society", "a stone-age society", "bombed back to the stone age", etc.

I've also been wondering how these terms apply to First World, Second World, Third World, etc. societies.

Say you have a First World society that has an apocalyptic event that destroys a certain number of critical infrastructures, such as electricity, digital technology, medical care, municipal water supplies, telecommunications, etc.

What do you call such societies? The term "post-apocalyptic" is overly broad -- there's minor collapse, partial collapse, total collapse, etc.

For example, an earthquake could reduce one First World city to shambles, eliminating all public utilities and societal structures, but the rest of the country and the world remain intact.

Or, consider a country like the Bahamas, where a single storm completely destroyed almost all parts of First World society, yet the country remains intact and they still have remnants of electricity, law, personal property, sanitation, etc.

So, it seems like there is a big difference between the Bahamas and Mad Max's world, yet I'm not familiar with any terminology for distinguishing these different stages of civilization.

It doesn't seem accurate to use the term "post-apocalyptic" for [the Bahamas](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/months-after-hurricane-dorian-abaco-islands-still-completely-devastated-n1105866), and [Puerto Rico](https://www.npr.org/2019/07/03/737001701/i-don-t-feel-safe-puerto-rico-preps-for-another-maria-without-enough-government), when you also have scenarios like [Mad Max's world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max) or that of the [Fallout franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout_(video_game)).

Are there names for post-disaster/post-apocalypse societies that exist at different stages, such as stone age, bronze age, industrial, First World, Second World, etc.?

EDIT: I think "degeneration theory" and modern survivalist/prepping cultures may have terms I am looking for. "Without Rule of Law/WROL" is one term that describes a specific.

Comment: The legal term is *[disaster area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_area)*. Once an area has been officially declared a disaster area (and, most likely, a *[state of emergency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_emergency)* has been enacted), *[disaster relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_management)* efforts (= "emergency management" in bureaucratese) can be funded from specially designated budgetary *[reserves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserve_(accounting))*.

Comment: Honestly this question *might* be a better fit for English Language SE... I'm not quite sure enough to flag it, but it's a thought.

Comment: @aslum I've been wondering the same thing, but since it deals mostly with as-yet unexperienced scenarios that currently most often occur in fiction, I thought I'd try here.

Comment: Thom, I think your query is wandering a bit, losing focus along the way. I think you're trying to ask two different questions here, one about a temporary setback (P.R., Bahamas after a major storm) vs a broader and more long term social trend. I'd invite you to consider which you're actually interested in, focus on that and edit your question accordingly. The question I thìnk you're asking (the long-term broader social question is of interest here as a matter of worldbuilding.

Comment: I'd also argue that, far from dealing with as of yet unexperienced scenarios, very many prominent civilisations have experienced exactly this kind of "collapse to a certain degree", and I believe Zeiss Ikon has your answer!

Comment: @elemtilas Well, my query is a bit open ended in the sense that I am currently preparing for an apocalypse of unknown scale. The degree to which my society is going to collapse is unknown at this current time, so the exact stage of collapse will determine exactly what types of preparations I or my country may need to make in order to recover successfully.

Comment: Ah, well, got you there! SE really isn't suited for open ended questions. Even here in WB.SE, we prefer focused, single-problem questions. Open ended questions are best addressed in a discussion forum.

Comment: FWIW generally no one really realizes the situation until well after. If society rebounds it's probably a "great depression" if it doesn't then it was a decline/fall. During the event you might call it a down-turn or they might say the X market bubble has burst.

Comment: @elemtilas My question is not really open ended unless there is no current scale of measuring societies post-apocalypse/post-disaster. Currently, we have a fully developed system terminology for past "ages", ie stone age, iron age, bronze age, and we also have a system describing past and existing societies, ie First World, Second, Third, Fourth, and Fifth World societies. So, I'm wondering if there is any such equivalent existing system for describing/categorizing civilizations after they wane.

Comment: Fair enough: then ask that question!  Forget about Bahamas and edit your query accordingly. I have the feeling that, even if I don't do it, someone else is going to come along and vote to close because of lack of focus, or worse, being too opinion based.

Comment: @elemtilas If it actually does get close voted, then that will be my answer -- there is no existing answer or terminology. So, either way.

Comment: Well, that's not what a close vote means...  In any event, you might consider looking into [Degeneration Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneration_theory). I'd propose that there is a continuum from "incipiency" to "ascendancy" to "decadence" to "failure" that mark points along a culture or society's development arc.

Comment: @elemtilas Yes! This is exactly what I'm looking for, although at first glance, it doesn't seem to include extremes such as Fallout/Mad Max. Thank you though!

Comment: I suppose "failed" and "post-apocalyptic" would run hand-in-hand! I'd still urge you very strongly to edit your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104712/discussion-between-thom-blair-iii-and-elemtilas).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its just asking for some one to use a dictionary or thesaurus to tell them a good word.

Comment: Same as @EDL. You might want to try on english.SE instead.

Answer (score 5):

The general term for a society that has fallen from its peak, regardless of the reason, is "decadent."  This word, however, often connotes a society that has "rotted from within", as the Roman Empire did, rather than one brought low by natural disaster, famine, or attacks from without.

Still, decadence can come about because a society failed to recognize and act on warning signs -- the peoples living near the Sahel might have been able to avoid the famines of the 1970s and 1980s if they'd recognized that overgrazing was expanding the desert, altering the very climate locally rather than simply killing the grass for the season.

Comment: Would you also call Mad Max's world "decadent"? Or that of Fallout? Decadent seems too mild to really convey the reality, even though it might be technically accurate in some way.

Comment: @ThomBlairIII As I noted, "decadent" has a connotation that's not part of its actual definition.    Bartertown is clearly decadent.  Haven't played *Fallout*.  Decadence is "fallen glory" -- "this used to be great, now not so much."

Comment: Mad Max is pretty clearly "post-apocalyptic". There has indeed been a world-shattering disaster (I think a nuclear war) that has pretty much destroyed civilisation. Now, in its local context, one could say that Bartertown is "decadent" -- but decadent compared to what, really? The rest of the post-pockyclyptic world?

Comment: @elemtilas Decadent compared to the society that could *make* the things they were scrabbling around trying to keep working (or using as hammers and swords).

Comment: Hm.  And since that society is now failed, due to it being post-pockyclyptic, I'm back to wondering if "decadent" can even be applied to Bartertown, in its own context.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding the qualifier "wounded" or "fallen" to a pre-disaster description of the location?  The choice of terms could imply the direction of progress...

The Bahama's would be a "Wounded Vacation Destination" because they are recovering.

A Mad-Max Australia would be a "Fallen 20th Century Nation" because they are not.

Answer (score 3):

A Dark Age typically refers to a time when a civilization is in a prolonged state of  collapse. The opposite of a Golden age. They tend to see a decline in art, literature, science, trade, etc.  Governments are typical localized, unstable, or corrupt beyond being functional.  Dark Ages are not post-apocalyptic bad because they tend to still have mostly functional towns and cities.

They tend to follow events such as:

- A major military losses where a nation's government is destroyed by an invasion, but not conquered by the attacker to reestablish order.
- Massive Plagues or Famines that kill off enough people to cripple infrastructure.
- A prolonged period of decadence where an aristocracy cripples the nation's wealth through over exploitation.
- A major economic shift where a nation's key resource suddenly become irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

In Ancient Greece, the past when the gods walked the Earth and did wonderful things was the "Golden Age", while the later eras when the gods had largely withdrawn but demigods and heroes walked the Earth was the "Silver Age".

People tend to think of the here and now and then apply this to comparisons, so a person living in a semi collapsed civilization which has lost many of its abilities might refer to their grandfather's time as "the golden age, when people still could use flying machines". In a few generations, the "golden age" will simply be described as the time when men flew....